# create_user() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-users

I try to create user use `User.objects.create_user`. But it show error.

**create_user() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 5 were given**

```
     myuser = User.objects.create_user(username , email, password, friendid)
```

Answer (score 2):

[create user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) expects keyword arguments:

```
 myuser = User.objects.create_user(username=username , email=email, password=password, friendid)
```